# CMake with vcpkg: how to link debug version of Qt?

Tags: qt, debugging, cmake, linker, vcpkg

I have read in the [Qt docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/debug.html) that:

> The Qt library contains hundreds of internal checks that will print warning messages when a programming error is detected. We therefore recommend that you use a debug version of Qt when developing Qt-based software.

So I want to link a "debug version of Qt" when compiling [PDF4QT](https://github.com/JakubMelka/PDF4QT).

It uses [CMake](https://cmake.org/) with [vcpkg](https://vcpkg.io/en/index.html) as package manager when configuring its build.

How can I do that?

I have tried appending `-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug` to the config line, but after using `ldd` on the generated binary I found out that the Release version of the Qt library is still used.

[EDIT] Here are the exact commands I issued:

```
cmake -B build_debug -S . -DPDF4QT_INSTALL_QT_DEPENDENCIES=0 -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=$VCPKG_PATH/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX='/' -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug
cmake --build build_debug --config Debug -j12
```

Then after compiling if I do for example `ldd ./build_debug/Pdf4QtViewerLite/Pdf4QtViewerLite` I get for example:

```
libQt6Widgets.so.6 => /usr/lib/libQt6Widgets.so.6
```

so it's still linked to the release build

Comment: Did you do a clean reconfigure after adding CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE?

Comment: What is a "clean reconfigure"? I have run `cmake -B build -S . -DPDF4QT_INSTALL_QT_DEPENDENCIES=0 -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=$VCPKG_PATH/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX='/' -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug` and then `--build`

Comment: "clean reconfigure" means you don't have a populated CMakeCache.txt. So delete build/ and try again. You might also need to use `--config Debug` for the build command since you didn't specify the (maybe default) Generator you used.

Comment: In reality I'm configuring the debug build in another folder altogether called `build_debug`. I will try the `--config` option

Comment: @AlexanderNeumann I did and nothing changed. See the edit.

Comment: Hmm run configure with `--trace-expand` and check in the logs if somebody is messing with `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE`. Because from the information given I don't see why it should not link the debug libraries.

Comment: Doesn't seem so. [here are the logs](http://0x0.st/Hjos.txt)

Comment: I think your `-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX='/'` is messing with the CMake lookup for Qt6 from vcpkg. If you look at the Qt6 stuff in the trace log you see that everything is coming from `/usr/lib/cmake/Qt6*`. Really don't define root as the install prefix use a staging dir for that.

Comment: No It still gets it from `/usr/lib`

Comment: Did you actually install Qt6 in vcpkg?  https://github.com/JakubMelka/PDF4QT/blob/aec54836901c11808fd99b3e5cdf6fe02e75d5cf/vcpkg.json#L4 does not.

Comment: that was it! Thanks. Please post it as an answer so I can accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the case of `PDF4QT` the vcpkg manifest does not specify `Qt6` via the port `qtbase` as a dependency. As such vcpkg is not going to install `Qt6` automatically and cmake will instead find the system installed Qt6. Since the system intalled Qt6 does not come with debug versions of the libraries it is not possible to linke against debug versions of the library.
However, if the manifest includes `Qt6` via `qtbase` (+ other required qt ports) it will be build by vcpkg and picked up by cmake. In that case `-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug` will be enough to select the debug version of the Qt6 libraries.